# Multidimensional array Matlab correlations

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, correlation

I have a matrix 50x120x185 named A, with the 50x120 being a series of latitude and longitude coordinates and 185 being the coordinates through time. 
And another variable 1x185 and I need to correlate this variable with each coordinate of the matrix through the third dimension time (185).

A= (50, 120, 185)

B=(1 2 3 4 5..)

I tried reshaping A with the following code:

```
D = reshape(A,[],size(A,3));
```

But when I tried to correlate

```
G = corr2(D',B');
```

I get the errors

```
Error using corr2>ParseInputs (line 39)
 A and B must be the same size.
 Error in corr2 (line 21)
 [a,b] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});
```

Does anyone know a different way to get my code to correlate the B with each latitude and longitude through the third dimension of A ?

Its worth noting that A has a lot of NaN's

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you are wanting to do 50x120=6000 correlations, each of them being the correlation between a 1x185 subset of A with all of B. If this is true you'll need to call `corr` for each of these correlations.

Try something like `arrayfun(@(i) corr(Ap(i,:),B), 1:size(Ap,1))`, where `Ap = reshape(A, [], size(A,3)`.